# Where are some good places to grind CP?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'm looking for some good places to grind CP. Ideally they would be:

- Relatively quick and painless fights. Mindless button mashing at its best.
- An amount of CP such that it *makes sense* to stop and grind there. If subsequent areas of the game are going to reward double or triple CP for the same level of difficulty then it's not a great grinding location.

Maybe 1 or 2 areas per episode? For those who aren't aware, the game is split into episodes until you've unlocked just about every area. Your growth is capped at fixed levels per episode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Academia -400AF 350-500 for quick match

Comment: +1 Cool thing about this place is that groups spawn even without you having to walk around.

Answer (score 3):

Well i know you said relatively painless fights but i have to post this. Yomi. All the way. 20000 CP each fight without x2 CP skill. Obviously more with it. +You get some good money from it. 144,000 Gil with x2 Durable Collectors Catalogs. Good luck!

Comment: Not to mention the chance to drop a Trapezohedron which you'll want to craft the top tier weapons.

Answer (score 2):

Village of Oerba 200AF. It's easy kills and around 200-300 CP a fight.

Answer (score 1):

Archlyte steppe, with stormy weather over near Yomi.  A few stronger and mediocre Cieth appear here; you can earn around 800-1200CP per fight if you have the CP boost fragment skill.

Comment: +1 I grind in Archlyte Steppe in rainy weather, in the water area. Mainly for the monster mats, but the CP isn't bad.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Oerba 400 and go down to the beach area and in battle you usually get 900-1,000+ cyristarium points. The beasts you will want to go up against are the behemoths and pith forked cieth cat.

Answer (score -1):

Try Bresha Ruins 300AF. I get 100-300 CP and 300 gil (double for me because I have Gilfinder). Also, you get some very useful materials. The best part is 10-second fights.

Comment: There are way better places to grind for cp and gil than this with fights giving 300~1200 cp per fight that are relatively painless