# Do you really get 30,000 CP for each fragment?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

This is a quote from this [website](http://segmentnext.com/2012/02/06/final-fantasy-13-2-gil-and-cp-farming-guide/):

> Final Fantasy 13-2 doesn’t really require much grinding compared to Final Fantasy 13. You should be able to level up each role to 99 just by collecting all fragments (See fragment Locations). Each fragment rewards 30,000 CP and collecting all fragments rewards you with Defragmented trophy so it’s worth the effort.

Are they telling the truth? Can you really get 30,000 CP just from getting one fragment?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the 4 bosses in the Archlyte Steppe AF yields 30,000 CP.

Answer (score 7):

Their claim is that each fragment gives you 30,000 CP: from my experience after collecting 120 fragments, only the four big game monsters (Ochu, Shaolong Gui, Immortal, and Yomi) and completing the game awarding 30,000 CP.

Additionally, paradox ending fragments each award 10,000 CP.

Most other fragments are usually the rewards for completing a side quest: the CP bonus you receive is just a quest reward and is somewhere between 200 and 1,000 CP. If you want to max out your crystarium grid (and your monsters' crystarium grids using monster materials), you'll be doing some grinding.

So while you technically can get 30,000 CP from a fragment, the site is indeed mistaken as there are only a small number of them that give that type of reward.

The site also claims each battle awards 1,000 CP off the bat: that's not even close to being correct. In first few areas, battles award something in the 25-100 CP range. The [question about grinding](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49372/where-are-some-good-places-to-grind-cp) has answers suggesting grind-worthy mobs cap out around 300–400 CP (which matches up with my experience), well below their claim of 1,000 CP being routine.

Comment: But you can gain 30k cp from some bosses right ? Can you maybe tell the names of those ? And are they really hard for someone who just now completed the main story without much cp grinding? My Noel has 4,7k hp and a bit over 500 ATK, Serah almost 3k hp Magic atk a bit over 500.

The site also claims each battle awards 1,000 CP off the bat: that's hilariously incorrect. In first few areas, battles award something in the 25-100 CP range.

They said that one can gain 1000 CP in Academia 400AF with the fragment skill "Grow Egg"

Comment: @InsaneX3 I'm not going to begin to guess what a random blog post that has laughably incorrect data could've possibly been referring to: the data they're claiming is simply wrong. Check out [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49372/3389) for help grinding CP.

Comment: @InsaneX3 Mark is right. And to your comment on boss fights - the fights themselves almost never reward CP. Some of the fights result in your gaining a fragment, which will also reward CP. So far I think the most I've seen from a fragment is 15k CP. That's just my personal experience / recollection.

Comment: The bosses I've fought so far all awarded 0cp and 0gil

Answer (score 0):

Ochu, Immortal, Long Gui, and Yomi (all located in the Steppe) all give fragments that give 30,000 CP. Unfortunately they are not easy to kill until near the end of leveling. With my maxed characters it only takes 45ish seconds to kill Ochu/Immortal and 1-2 mins for Long Gui. Yomi still takes a few mins (3-6 usually) but well worth it since with 2 Durable Collectors Catalogs it also gives 144,000 gil. =) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

That info is incorrect. Not every fragment is worth 30,000 CP.

There is only one with 30,000 CP that I know of, and that is the last boss which you fight in Academia AF 500, after defeating Chaos Bahamut, Caius-Caius-Caius, Jet, Garnet, Amber Bahamuts.

You will receive Academia Fragment, Paradox Scope [2/2], 30,000 CP and you also unlock AF?

Valhalla Timeline and Hope Gate Seal (Time Reversal for AF? Valhalla). The other high end CP are Yomi are Long Gui amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Raspatil gives 50,000 cp and 50,000 gil. Just killed him roughly 5 minutes ago : )

Comment: The question is talking about fragment CP, not monster CP.

Answer (score -1):

Some bosses like Yomi give you 50,000 for the fragment and 40,000 for the monster itself. Also i found a rare monster in oreba 400af that gives you 50,000cp per battle plus 50k gil but it's an 11 min battle even for maxed out characters. It's one of those fussy black orb paradox things it has 3,666,000 hp.

Comment: These numbers are way off. You get 30,000 for four specific monster fragments (Ochu, Yomi, Shaolong Gui, and Immortal) and that's a one-time deal. Yomi gives 20,000 CP per kill, not 40,000. The monster you're referring to (Raspatil) is 25,000 CP per kill.